# When solving system's of equation what does t represent in this problem and when/why does it occur?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

*4 x - y + z = 5*

*2 y + 6 z = 3 0*

*x + z = 5*

**I had set up a matrices based on the equations above and formed:**

```
4  -1  1   5

0  2   6   30 

0  0   8   0
```

In the question it stated:

**Solve the system if possible. (If a free variable is needed use the parameter t. If the system is inconsistent, enter INCONSISTENT.)** When searching up how to answer this problem, i was left confused since their was a variable called t I left out according to the question so how do i approach these types of problems in general.

~ Thankyou if you can explain how to do these problems in full anywho.

Comment: The question says "if a free variable is needed use the parameter $t$".  In your case there is a unique solution, so no free variable needed, so just forget about $t$.  (Note: I am assuming your working is correct, I haven't checked it.)

Comment: The system does not have a unique solution. One way of writing the solution set is $\{(t,3t,5-t)\}$ I have used x itself as a parameter and denoted it by t.